# HTML label association with inputs; bad UX?

Tags: forms, accessibility, html, labeling

I'm a web developer having a weird UX issue.  When I build HTML forms, I ensure that every input's label is implemented through a `<label></label>` tag and that each label uses the `for` attribute to associate it with the input.  For example:

```
<label for="firstName">First Name</label>
<input id="firstName" type="text" />

<label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
<input id="lastName" type="text" />
```

This follows what I've always heard is an accessibility best practice.  It also has what I consider an added benefit of focusing the input when the label is clicked.

Others here disagree on that last point.

They actually say that it's weird that clicking the label focuses the input, and that it's "non-standard" behavior.  Since I'm using what I consider standard HTML practices, I would think that is is indeed standard.  Perhaps this is just their reaction to the fact that other pages in the site doesn't use real labels and don't have this behavior, but they seem to genuinely hate this label behavior.

I don't understand.  Am I in the wrong here?  Is it considered bad UX practice to have labels focus an input?  If so, why?  If I need to fix this, is there an alternate way to make an input more accessible without using a label?

Comment: Sometimes 'others' are wrong. Very very wrong.

Comment: "They actually say that it's weird that clicking the label focuses the input, and that it's "non-standard" behavior."

And my answer is: So what? Associating the label with the input has no downsides (or at least, none that they brought up to you). The alternative is that clicking the label does nothing, so you lose something and gain nothing in return.

When saying something shouldn't be done, you should list some downsides other than "it's not standard". If we only ever did everything the way it's been done before we would never make any progress in anything.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I cannot understand why you'd want a reduced click area for your form field. Including the "for" attribute on the label tag allows you to increase the clickable area. It has been a web standard for quite a while and I would think most users are used to the behavior at this point, making it a convention. While it may not be a convention in software, I would definitely consider it a web convention.

The best benefit here is for sure [increased accessibility](http://www.usability.com.au/resources/wcag2/) (see the section on form input labels).

I do not think this simply applies to check boxes and radio buttons. I have seen cases where it's handy to use for text inputs as well, although definitely not as much of a help as with radio buttons and check boxes.

You can see also that [W3Schools mentions it as a usability improvement right in there reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp), while admittedly it may not be the best reference. However, if you look at the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1) the label tag's "for" attribute is to ensure it is explicitly associated with another control, and the specification explicitly mentions that "When a LABEL element receives focus, it passes the focus on to its associated control".

As with this [web design blog](http://line25.com/articles/10-usability-crimes-you-really-shouldnt-commit), I also find that it is a usability "crime" when the field and the label are left unassociated.

Comment: Good answer, but I should point out that W3Schools is most certainly NOT the same as W3C. Please read http://w3fools.com/ for details.

Comment: Whoops, totally missed that this time around. I did know that in the back of my head somewhere. Updated the post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. These links will be helpful if I need to continue justifying my use of labels.

Comment: This can be helpful on a touchscreen,  too, where an input field may be hard to focus on without zooming.

Comment: I created an account to upvote this answer and question.  I hate interacting with forms which have foregone this simple practice.

Comment: TomG - you're right, bigger clickable areas are very useful on touch screens, although annoyingly labels do not by default activate the input in iOS - extra javascript it required for this functionality.

Comment: Agree 100% in that increasing the click area increases the usability.

Answer (score 18):

Those 'others' are incorrect. This *is* the intention of the HTML label tag and the proper implementation. Aside from the accessibility necessity, it's also a huge UX benefit especially with things such as checkboxes, where it's usually easier to hit the label than the tiny checkbox.

If these 'others' hate it, tell them to stop clicking on the labels. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is not common in user interfaces, and it probably just reflects how `label` works for checkboxes and radio buttons (clicking on the label toggles the state, and *this* corresponds to common UX design and is *very* useful). For textboxes, the feature is neither particularly useful nor harmful. Any attempt to prevent it with JavaScript probably causes problems instead of solving any, and not using `label` is bad for accessibility (since assistive software makes *other* use for `label` markup).

Answer (score 1):

This is quite debatable.

For a **touch device**, expanding the clickable area, especially in the case of text input may actually be counter-productive if the user's intention is to scroll down the form instead of filling the input.

Comment: if your users need to scroll down your form, it's probably too big

Comment: @RossMcKinley, I disagree. A phone display is usually too small. It is perfectly reasonable for a bit of scrolling.

Comment: @RossMcKinley Anything but the most trivial of forms is likely to scroll on a mobile device. It doesn't mean the form is too big.

Comment: You need to ask why they would need to scroll. Is it to find out what's being asked? Why don't they know already? If a user lands on a form page, there should be no need to scroll, just fill in the information they're there to fill in.

Comment: @RossMcKinley they may need to scroll to edit a field they've already entered. They may need to scroll to see what they entered in a previous field. They may need to scroll because they are applying for a passport which requires 2,000 field inputs...

Comment: @JonW If any of those scenarios are the case, the form is badly designed. Sure, in some cases it's unavoidable. In any case, the OS should determine between taps and drags.

Comment: @RossMcKinley: Well if you're able to design a passport application form that fits on an iphone screen in a usable, easy way (including displaying any feedback / error text) - so basically in about 4 text fields - I'd be pretty impressed.

Comment: @JonW It's not impossible to design a complex information gathering strategy with multiple parts. Most complex forms can (and should) be subcategorised. And these sub categories should be editable individually, and then saved separately. It's very unlikely that you'll want to go back and edit your name, or place of birth, during a lengthy form filling process. Clever categorisation of fields will lead to a much better UX. One that doesn't require the user to be jumping around the form wondering what they put where